# From socially inclined to a coping strategy

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> You are something nerds cannot obtain
>   Change your swear to a language so you connect dots
>   Move your en to the finish to hold someone's property
>   Change your en to a swear to do something happily
>   Move from hell to a growl to cope with a tragic experience

What have you turned into, and how?

Comment: I don't mean to offend you, but these puzzles just seem... low-effort - like they're easily mass-produced. I suggest adding some rhyme and meter to make them look like you spent more time on them.

Comment: @Deusovi Honestly these puzzles are just made to be quick and fun. I don't post here often anymore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Proposed Solution:

> **LIFE -> GRIEF**

You are something nerds cannot obtain

> Life : Nerds have no life, as the saying goes.

Change your swear to a language so you connect dots

> Life -> Line : "F" is an abbreviation of a particular swear word; change the f to n.

Move your en to the finish to hold someone's property

> Line -> Lien

Change your en to a swear to do something happily

> Lien -> Lief (see above for explanation of F)

Move from hell to a growl to cope with a tragic experience

> Lief -> **Grief** : change L (sounds like "hell") to GR ("grr" is an onomatopoeia of a growl)

Comment: If nerds can't obtain that, I'm assuming SE is a bunch of single people (I say as I sit here married).

Comment: That's what I was thinking. But it is the only clue that fits between the others.

Comment: It's actually "A spot on 'The Jersey Shore' ”

Comment: I think I figured it out. Not entirely sure; I hope someone can come along and suggest edits to the explanations.

Comment: Can you explain the swear parts?

Comment: @gannolloy: "F" or "the F word" is a commonly used stand-in for a swear that starts with F.

Comment: @gannolloy i made an edit to show my interpretation of the swear parts

Comment: This is correct

Comment: How is 'n' a language?

Comment: @warspyking: If it is correct, why don't you accept Bulldogg6404's answer?

Comment: @fondor Not everything is explained

Comment: As I do not entirely care what the correct explanations are, I will leave them for someone else to determine (and you may award their answer with the acceptance - I am satisfied with knowing I answered correctly). Assuming nobody comes to try to figure out whatever minute details are left to explain, it shall be your decision whether or not to leave this riddle marked incomplete.

Comment: @warspyking I think you should accept, but "shift" the acceptance to a better answer, if one comes around. Doesn't seem anybody is picking up on this.

Comment: @BmyGuest You're probably right, but if the s answer is accepted it's doubtful others will attempt to elaborate on the details.

Comment: @warspyking That's likely true. However, if you feel your puzzle deserves more "solution", nothing is wrong with writing a comunity-answer "as intended".